# Using multiple security providers for each URI in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, security, fosuserbundle, symfony-security

Straight forward to question, How can I use different security providers for different URI patterns in `security.yml`?, here is the scenario:

there are some URIs in `routing.yml` as follow:

- `/` with no security and available for everyone
- `/admin` which is only accessible for registered users and uses `fos_userbundle` as security provider
- `/api` which is granted only for users with some `apiKey` property in entity.

there are two different User entities in database, `User` and `ApiUser`. And here is my `security.yml`:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    acl:
        connection: default

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        api_domain:
            entity:
                class: AdministrationUserBundle:ApiUser
                property: apiKey

        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        # Disabling the security for the web debug toolbar, the profiler and Assetic.
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        # -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL
        admin:
            pattern:            /admin(.*)
            context:            user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /admin/login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /admin/login_check
                failure_path:   null
                success_handler: admin_success_handler
            logout:
                path:           /admin/logout
            anonymous:          true

        # Custom firewall for api area
        api_login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false

        api_doc:
            pattern: ^/api/doc
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            guard:
                provider: api_domain
                entry_point: app.token_authenticator
                authenticators:
                    - app.token_authenticator
            lexik_jwt: ~
        # -> end custom configuration

        # default login area for standard users

        # This firewall is used to handle the public login area
        # This part is handled by the FOS User Bundle
        main:
            pattern:             .*
            context:             user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:             true
            anonymous:          true

    access_control:
        # URL of FOSUserBundle which need to be available to anonymous users
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Admin login page needs to be access without credential
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Secured part of the site
        # This config requires being logged for the whole site and having the admin role for the admin part.
        # Change these rules to adapt them to your needs
        - { path: ^/assets/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/uploads/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN] }
        - { path: ^/user/, role: [ROLE_USER] }
        - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/card/, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching and bug fixings, I found that the easiest way to achieve it, is to use Regex, so I changed my `security.yml`:

```
    api:
        pattern:   ^/api/v\d+\.\d+/
        provider: api_domain
        anonymous: false
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - app.token_authenticator
        lexik_jwt: ~

    api_login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        provider: fos_userbundle
        form_login:
            check_path:               /api/login_check
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false

    api_doc:
        pattern: ^/api/doc
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
```

and in `routers.yml` added a version at the end of api uri:

```
rest:
    type : rest
    resource : "routers/rest_api.yml"
    prefix : /api/v1.2
```